# Validation problems with multiple checkboxes (HABTM) on CakePHP form

Tags: cakephp

**Short version**

I have some HABTM checkboxes on a form. Validation is working correctly (at least one checkbox needs to be checked for validation to pass) but the CakePHP error message divs aren't being generated as they should be.

**Long Version**

I have a from which allows users to fill in their name and email address and then choose from a list of brochures (checkboxes) they'd like to receive.

The form looks like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Request',array('action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('id');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('Brochure',array(
        'label' => __('Information Required:',true),
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $list,
        'selected' => $this->Html->value('Brochure.Brochure'),
));
echo $this->Form->submit('Submit');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

In my controller, `$list` is set as like this:

```
$this->Request->Brochure->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','name')));
```

After reading the 2nd answer (posted by user448164) in [HABTM form validation in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044102/habtm-form-validation-in-cakephp) on Stack Overflow, I set my Request model up like this:

```
<?php

class Request extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Request';

function beforeValidate() {
    foreach($this->hasAndBelongsToMany as $k=>$v) {
        if(isset($this->data[$k][$k]))
        {
            $this->data[$this->alias][$k] = $this->data[$k][$k];
        }
    }
}

var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter your full name'
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
    ),
    'Brochure' => array(
        'rule' => array('multiple', array('min' => 1)),
        'message' => 'Please select 1'
    ),
);
?>
```

This actually works 99% well. If none of the checkboxes are checked, validation fails as it should do. However, the only problem is that Cake isn't setting the "error" class on the `<div>`, nor is it creating the `<div class="error-message">Please select 1</div>` as it should.

For name and email, there is no problem - the error divs are being created properly.

So, to clarify, validation **is** working for my HABTM checkboxes. The only problem is that the error divs aren't being generated.

Comment: What cake version, and what does `$this->validationErrors` look like?

Comment: @jeremyharris I'm using Cake 2.1.1 but I've actually had this problem since Cake 1.3.x. `$this->validationErrors` is null but `$this->Request->validationErrors` gives me the array containing the 'Please select 1' error message I set in the model.

Comment: Yes but what's the format of the validation error array? That's how Cake determines if a field should show the error. You'll probably need to massage it a bit, which is what I'm getting at, something like the answer given in the question you linked to.

Comment: @jeremyharris Yes, you're right, the Accepted Answer in the question I linked to actually works perfectly. I tried it before and it wasn't working but I've made some model changes since then so I guess it was that. Sorry to waste your time. I have flagged this as a duplicate question.

Comment: No waste, don't worry. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this here as this is actually a much better question than [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044102/habtm-form-validation-in-cakephp) you found.

I was banging my head against a wall trying to handle the same problem of getting the validation error to show up in the page. I'm using CakePHP v1.2 and I hit a similar problem although I have actually split out the HABTM into the individual tables i.e. `Request->BrochuesRequest->Brochure`. This is because I can't have it deleting and re-adding the joining table rows at will.

Firstly I think the [accepted answer from your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044739/327074) assumes that you are doing a `save / saveAll` when the `beforeValidate` call is triggered, however I was doing it through a `validates` call. The difference is that you need to call the `Request->set` method first. It was an article by Jonathan Snook on [Multiple Validation Sets](http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/multiple_validation_sets_cakephp/) pointed me to that issue.

The second issue is actually getting the error message to appear was down to the `$field` value you use when calling `invalidate`. For ages I was including the model as well as the field assuming that this was how it matched the invalidate call to the input, i.e. you have `$form->input('BrochuresRequest.brochures_id')` so you need `$this->BrochuresRequest->invalidate('BrochuresRequest.brochures_id')`.

However that is **wrong** you just want `$this->BrochuresRequest->invalidate('brochures_id')`.

```
<?php   
// requests/add view
echo $form->input('BrochuresRequest.brochures_id', array('multiple' => true));

// requests_controller
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Request->create();
        // critical set to have $this->data 
        // for beforeValidate when calling validates
        $this->Request->set($this->data); 
        if ($this->Request->validates()) {
            $this->Request->saveAll($this->data);
        }
    }
}

// request model
function beforeValidate() {
    if (count($this->data['BrochuresRequest']['brochures_id']) < 1) {
        $this->invalidate('non_existent_field'); // fake validation error on Project
        // must be brochures_id and not BrochuresRequest.brochures_id
        $this->BrochuresRequest->invalidate('brochures_id', 'Please select 1');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

A few of the other things that I picked up on the way through:

1. You don't need a [separate $form->error in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841653/327074)
2. I couldn't for the life of me get the 'multiple' validation rule to work in the model
3. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2044739/327074) checks for an isset but I believe that this isn't required and masked the problem of there being no `$this->data` being passed through.
4. The `beforeValidate` should return false if you want it to prevent any save action.

Comment: Wow, this was a long time ago, but the code is still in use so I'll go back into it when I have a moment and try what you suggested. I'll be back to mark this as the accepted answer if it works out :-)